# getItemViewType for Image And Video

Tags: android

I'm trying to recyclerview multiple view types like Images in image viewholder and video in video viewholder...
everything working fine when im using this code

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //if (mediaObjects.get(position).getMedia_url().contains(".mp4")) {
    if (mediaObjects.get(position).getMedia_url().contains(".mp4")) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;

    
}
```

is there any best way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question is this

```
String filePath = "mediaName.mp4"; 
String type = someFilepath.substring(someFilepath.lastIndexOf("."));
```

or

```
 ContentResolver contentResolver= getContentResolver();
 MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
 String type = mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
```